# Attemping to pass data from one variable to another in a separate user control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

i would like to pass data from a text box in one user control and store it inside of a variable in another user control.

so far I've created an instance of the class that i would like to pass data to and then initialized it within the constructor of the user control:

```
private Uc_inputtingPaymentDetails _InputtingPaymentDetails;

  public Uc_bookingDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          
        creationOfSqlDataFunctions();
        _InputtingPaymentDetails = new Uc_inputtingPaymentDetails();
                
    }
```

I have then created a public string inside of the user control where i would like to store my data:

```
public string CoachId { get; set; }
```

when clicking a confirm button, I have called this string as shown below, to store the value of the text box inside of the CoachID string, however after placing breakpoints at this line it says that the CoachId is null. Does anyone know why this is?

```
   private void confirmBookingBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        _InputtingPaymentDetails.CoachId = txtCoachId.Text; // **this is where im trying to store the txtCoachId.Text value inside of the CoachId string variable.**
       
        string query_1 = "UPDATE Coach set numberOfSeats = numberOfSeats-1 WHERE Coach.CoachId = ' "+int.Parse(txtCoachId.Text)+" ' ";
        string query = "Insert into Bookings (departingFrom, destination, dateOfJourney, seatNo, ticketType, price, scheduleId, customerId ) VALUES (' " + txtDeparting.Text + " ',' " + txtDestination.Text + " ',' " + txtDepartureDate.Text + " ',' " + selectedSeatNo + " ',' " + txtTicketType.Text + " ',' " + txtPrice.Text + " ',' " + txtSchedule.Text + " ',' " + SignIn.userDetails[0] + " ' )";

        if (selectedSeatNo == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please ensure you have reserved a seat for your journey");
        }
        else 
        {                               
            _IsqlDataFunctions.ManagingData(query);
            _IsqlDataFunctions.ManagingData(query_1);
            ShowUserControl(new User_Control.Uc_inputtingPaymentDetails());
        }
                            
    }
```

By the way, I know I shouldn't be using concatenated strings for sql queries. I will be changing this soon.

Comment: Don't know if we see enough to understand the logic, but I see two versions of `new Uc_inputtingPaymentDetails()`, so my guess would be you aren't referencing the control on the screen.

Comment: hm, actually that could be the reason why. I'll change ShowUserControl(new User_Control.Uc_inputtingPaymentDetails()); to  ShowUserControl(_inputtingPaymentDetails()); and see what happens

Comment: yeah, that was the reason why. Can't believe i never noticed that myself :/ Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, I find that I can pass the variable CoachId successfully.

Therefore, you can check if the following code is working for you.

BookUserControl:(Add a button and a textbox)

```
 public partial class BookUserControl : UserControl
    {
        private PaymentUserControl pay;
        public BookUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pay = new PaymentUserControl();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pay.CoachId = textBox1.Text;
            MessageBox.Show(pay.CoachId);
        }
    }
```

PaymentUserControl:

```
 public partial class PaymentUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public PaymentUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string CoachId { get; set; }
    }
```

I add the BookUserControl to the form1, and I can get a messagebox about CoachId when I click the button.